# How to re-run failed testcases after running a suite in testNg

Tags: java, selenium, testng

Below is the testcase in testNg.xml

```
`<test name="Subset_TC01">
        <parameter name="InputExcelPath" value="Subset_TC01.xls" />
        <classes>
            <class name="com.idp.testcases.nbp.Mainflow">
                <methods>
                    <include name="testLogin" />
                    <include name="testLandingPage" />
                    <include name="testSearch" />
                    <include name="testInsuredInformationPage" />
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
<test name="Subset_TC02">
        <parameter name="InputExcelPath" value="Subset_TC02.xls" />
        <classes>
            <class name="com.idp.testcases.nbp.Mainflow">
                <methods>
                    <include name="testLogin" />
                    <include name="testLandingPage" />
                    <include name="testSearch" />
                    <include name="testInsuredInformationPage" />
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>`
```

Code i tried.

```
`public class RetryAnalyzerImpl implements IRetryAnalyzer{
    private int retryCount = 0;
     private int maxRetryCount = 1;
    @Override
    public boolean retry(ITestResult arg0) {
        if(retryCount < maxRetryCount) { 
            retryCount++; 
            return true; 
            } 
        return false; 
        } 
    }`
```

But this will only re-run the failed **testmethod** alone, not the whole testcase.

[image: Example Test Result:]

Please help me to find a solution to re-run the whole testcase **automatically** (For eg: Subset_TC01 , in this case)

Comment: I don't think there is a way to re-run whole test (xml test). as a workaround you can set dependency of your test cases and so in re-run it may run dependent test case as well, not sure though

Comment: can we extract the failed <test> </test> and then create a suite to run from java

Comment: `IRetryAnalyzer` is for test method retrying only and TestNG doesn't provide any way to retry something else.

Comment: @juherr : Thanku